# SQL join of multiple tables

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

How can I SELECT to show custid's who have a loan but no dda and no related actype unless only that of actype L?  Looking for records without a dda relation, not even if they are joint related (cfrela = J).
As below, A123 and B128 qualify but then the related A123 D actype disqualifies because of a joint relation to a DDA account.
L=Loan, D=DDA, S=Savings

```
SELECT loans.custid, dda.custid, related.custid
FROM data.lnmast lnmast 
EXCEPTION JOIN data.dda dda         
ON loans.custid = dda.custid
JOIN data.related related
ON loans.custid = related.custid

LOANS       
custid(c)   actype(c)   
A123           L    
B128           L    

DDA     
custid(c)   actype(c)   
A125           D    

RELATED     
custid(c)   actype(c) cfrela(c)
A123          D         J
A123          L         P
A123          S         J
B128          L         P
B128          L         P
```

Comment: So to clarify, are you saying that for loans you want the row regardless of whether there is a matching dda record, but all other types only if there is no matching dda record?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to show customer ids that do not exist in the dda table and only exist in the related table with actype = L?

```
SELECT L.CustId
FROM Loans L 
   LEFT JOIN Related R ON L.custid = R.custId AND R.actype <> 'L'
   LEFT JOIN DDA D ON L.custid = D.custid
WHERE d.custid IS NULL AND R.custid is NULL
```

And if there has to be a record in the Related table, then add one more INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.CustId
FROM Loans L 
   INNER JOIN Related R1 ON L.custid = R1.custId AND R1.actype = 'L'
   LEFT JOIN Related R ON L.custid = R.custId AND R.actype <> 'L'
   LEFT JOIN DDA D ON L.custid = D.custid
WHERE d.custid IS NULL AND R.custid is NULL
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is with `left outer join`:

```
select l.*
from data.lnmast l left outer join
     (select *
      from data.dda
      where actype <> 'L'
     ) dda
     on l.custid = dda.custid left outer join
     data.related r
     on l.custid = dda.custid
where dda.custid is null and r.custid is null
```

The `where` clause then selects the records that do not match, as per your logic.